# Display JSON error respone from webAPI request

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2, dynamics-crm-365

I have the following when i make a request to the CRM webapi:

```
Request URL:https://********.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/leads(******************)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.sms_ConvertLeadtoContact
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:10.160.2.19:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

In Chrome for the Response in the debugger I get the following JSON:

[image]

How do I display the Message section of the error ?

I tried JSON.parse(this.error) but no joy.

Thanks

Comment: Show the snippet where you handle the response.

Comment: First parse the string to JSON `JSON.parse(response)` then extract `message` from it `obj.message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for the responses.

I guess I found the anwser here:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/rdt/2016/01/13/executing-custom-action-via-javascript/

```
var errorMessage = JSON.parse(this.resposne).error;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your resp is the object that you have 
just try this:

```
resp.error.message
```

the example

```
var a={"error":{"code":"","message":"sdcsdcsdcsdc"}}
 //a.error.message
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have that response, then you'll need to parse this string like that:

```
var data = JSON.parse(YOUR_VARIABLE_WITH_THAT_RESPONSE);
var errorMessage = data.error.message;
```

Where `YOUR_VARIABLE_WITH_THAT_RESPONSE` contains string like that:

```
'{"error": { "message": "error message from your web api here..." }}'
```

That's all you need :)